# why does mui pagination changing the page cause scroll to the bottom?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, scroll, pagination

I'm using mui pagination in my react/next project. I want the pagination to cause screen scroll to top on changing. the problem is when I change page from 1 to 2, the screen scrolls to bottom in firefox browser (it works perfect in google chrome). Strangely, It's ok when I change page form 2 to 1!
This is My pagination code:

```
 <>
     <div className='hidden sm:block w-full'>
   <Pagination className={cssClass}
     sx={paginationCssStyles}
     onChange={changePage}
     page={page}
     dir='ltr' count={count} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
     </div>

     <div className='block sm:hidden w-full'>
   <Pagination className={cssClass}
     sx={paginationCssStyles}
     size='small'
     onChange={changePage}
     page={page}
     dir='ltr' count={count} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
     </div>
   </>
```

And this is onChange function:

```
//to change page of pagination
 const changePage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, value: number) => {
  
    setCurrentPage(value)
  
  if(value!=currentPage){
 
  if(typeof window!=undefined){
//skip is pagination parameter determines how many data we should skip
    localStorage.setItem("skip",((value-1)*(courses.length)).toString())
    getDataFromApi()
   
  
  }
}
if (typeof window !== undefined) {

  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

 
};
```